# Set focus and show element doesn't work simultaneously

Tags: html, angular

It's a minimal example. I'm trying to show a textarea and the set the focus onto it. It doesn't work. If the textarea is visible, the focus works good but after making the textarea visible, it loses the focus. Why?

```
<div class="posts">
    <div class="post">
        <textarea #textarea1 [(ngModel)]="text" class="comment-text" name="text"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button (click)="textarea1.focus()">SetFocus on the first textarea</button>
    <br><br>
    <div class="post">

        <textarea #textarea2 [(ngModel)]="text" [hidden]="!show" class="comment-text" name="text"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button (click)="show = !show; textarea2.focus()">SetFocus on the second textarea</button>

</div>
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ebe7gc

Comment: Can you explain little more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time the hidden attribute gets false the focus() command can't get the textarea. 
With a small setTimeout() you can solve that problem.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-01-angular-4tl2u

```
  showAndFocus(elem) {
    this.show = !this.show;    
    setTimeout(() => {
      elem.focus();
    },10);
  }
```

```html
<button (click)="showAndFocus(textarea2)">SetFocus on the second textarea</button>
```

Comment: you needn't use ',10', Angular yet await to the "second round" to make the focus:`setTimeout(() => { elem.focus();});`

Answer (score 0):

```
     <div class="posts">
        <div class="post">
            <textarea #textarea1 [(ngModel)]="text" class="comment-text" name="text"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button (click)="textarea1.focus() ; textarea2.focus=false">SetFocus on the first textarea</button>

        <br><br>
        <div class="post">


            <textarea #textarea2 [(ngModel)]="text" [hidden]="!show"  class="comment-text" name="text"></textarea>

   {{ textarea2.focus() }}
        </div>
        <button (click)= "show = !show " >SetFocus on the second textarea</button>

    </div>
```

Comment: add this in your second textarea , it's working  `{{ textarea2.focus() }}` i hope this is helpes

Comment: Well... the focus doesn't disappear any more. Try to set the focus again to textarea1 - it doesn't work while textarea2 is visible.